# STM32 Не работает функция HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA

Tags: stm32, uart

Камень STM32F103C8, создаю проект в CubeMX, настраиваю стандартно - USART2 в режим Asynchronous, активирую его глобальное прерывание, создаю DMA канал:[image: Создание DMA канала]

Генерирую проект и дописываю в while следующий код:

```
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2, buff, 100);
      HAL_Delay(100);
  }
```

Компилирую, прошиваю и... ничего! На ноге Tx всё время высокий уровень, ни намёка на передачу.
В то же время функция HAL_UART_Transmit_IT работает отлично, этот же код с аналогичной настройкой работает на STM32F407VG(Discovery). Пробовал другие камни F103C8, пробовал в разных местах вызывать HAL_UART_Abort, HAL_DMA_Abort - безуспешно.

---

Заметил, что сразу же после вызова HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA вызывается обработчик прерывания DMA, в котором HAL выносит вердикт, что передача завершена, что бы это значило? HAL сломался?

---

P.S. Привожу код инициализации USART-a и DMA

```
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 100;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_2;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel7_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel7_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel7_IRQn);

}
```

Comment: Покажите функцию инициализации Uart и DMA. Может быть у вас просто что-то не проинициализировано. Могу также привести свой код инициализации, но пока  - это преждевременно. Сначала, покажите, что у вас .

Comment: Добавил........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде не инициализирован DMA. Ниже привожу кусок своего кода:

```
void StandardUart::initialize()
{

    ...
    // инициализируем сам Uart
    mHUart->Init.BaudRate = UART_BAUD_RATE;
    mHUart->Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    mHUart->Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    mHUart->Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    mHUart->Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    mHUart->Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    mHUart->Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;

    //NOTE: Покамест оставил без дополнительной инициаизации
    // DMA initialization
    /* DMA controller clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /*##-3- Configure the DMA ##################################################*/
    /* Configure the DMA handler for Transmission process */
    static DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tx; //никуда не должен деться
    hdma_tx.Instance                 = DMA1_Channel4;
    hdma_tx.Init.Direction           = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_tx.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_tx.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_tx.Init.Mode                = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_tx.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;

    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_tx);

    /* Associate the initialized DMA handle to the UART handle */
    __HAL_LINKDMA(mHUart, hdmatx, hdma_tx);

    /* Configure the DMA handler for reception process */
    static DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_rx;
    hdma_rx.Instance                 = DMA1_Channel5;
    hdma_rx.Init.Direction           = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_rx.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_rx.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_rx.Init.Mode                = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_rx.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;

    HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_rx);
    /* Associate the initialized DMA handle to the the UART handle */
    __HAL_LINKDMA(mHUart, hdmarx, hdma_rx);


    /* DMA interrupt init */
    /* DMA1_Channel4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn);
    /* DMA1_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);

    // UART initialization
    // подключаем тактирование самого USART
    IRQn_Type Irq = USART1_IRQn;
    if (mHUart->Instance == USART2){
        __HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();
        Irq = USART2_IRQn;
    }
    if (mHUart->Instance == USART3){
        __HAL_RCC_USART3_CLK_ENABLE();
        Irq = USART3_IRQn;
    }

    HAL_UART_DeInit(mHUart);
    HAL_UART_Init(mHUart);

    /* Peripheral interrupt init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(Irq, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(Irq);

    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(mHUart,
                         mRxBuffer,
                         MaxBufferSize);
}
```

Что видно:

- нет инициализации DMA. `HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_tx)`
- нет линковки DMA с UART `__HAL_LINKDMA(mHUart, hdmatx, hdma_tx)`
- в коде не вижу включение тактирования UART `__HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();`

Comment: Да, действительно, с HAL всё в порядке, дело было в неинициализированной DMA, спасибо!